# Energy Density of Radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

What actually does the term energy density u(v,T) denotes? Is it the energy density of cavity radiation or the radiation emitted by blackbody? Is it uniform? While we derive an expression of it , we consider cavity radiation and use this expression in proving Stefan’s Law.I am confused.Please explain.

Comment: Please explain this problem

Comment: Are you asking about the spectral energy density?

Comment: Yes , the spectral energy density.

Comment: By the way, the usual symbol for the angular frequency is the lowercase Greek letter nu ($\nu$) rather than a lowercase Roman letter vee (v). You can get the former by [using the MathJax typesetting engine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) active on the site; write math between dollar signs (or double dollar signs) for inline (block-set) equations and use `\nu`, `\alpha` and so on for greek letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine I build a device which will (quite suddenly) close a set of walls around a volume of space. And the walls are perfectly transparent except in a narrow frequency band near $\nu$ where there are perfectly reflecting.

If I stick the machine into a cavity and close it, I will capture some light (all with frequency $\nu$) inside the newly formed box, and I can transport it somewhere and then let it out and measure how much energy was carried therein.<sup>1</sup>

Now, I know the volume $V$ of the box and the total energy $E$ of the light trapped therein, so I can compute $u = u(\nu) = \frac{E}{V}$. WIth lots of boxes I could do that for many frequency bands.

Finally, if I experiment with the light grabber in cavities of different temperatures I will find that

1. The energy density is largely independent of the material of the cavity.<sup>2</sup>
2. The densities are strongly dependent on the band I select.
3. The densities are strongly dependent on the temperature of the cavity.

So it makes sense in this case to write the energy density as a function of frequency and temperature:
$$u = u(\nu,T)\,.$$

---

<sup>1</sup> Or if I can make precise enough measurement I can even measure the change in the boxes mass.

<sup>2</sup>Here I am assuming that the thermal spectrum overwhelms discrete excitations.